# How to pass a specific object to a function through an html link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently I am working on a site where I receive a list of objects from a data base and I am listing them in a pop-up table. I'd like one column of the table to list the object id and another to list links which call a function for that specific object. My issue is that I do not know how to do this when appending this data to a table.

Any ideas?

```
 var tableContent ="<tr>";
            for( var i =0; i<results.length ; i++)
            {
              tableContent += "<td>" + results[i].get("id") + "</td>"
              tableContent += "<td>" + "<a>Open ID Contents</a>" + "</td>" 
  //I want this link to pass results[i] to a function^
                }
                tableContent += "</tr>"
                $("#List").append(tableContent)
```

Comment: Can you show us your database data and html also?  It would be easier to answer with more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct your `a` items in this way:

```
var $a = $('<a class="hasPopupData">...</a>');
$a.data('popup', { /*Your data goes here */ });
$a.appendTo($parent);
```

And then handle clicks using code like this:

```
$parentTable.on('click', 'a.hasPopupData', function(){
  var $a = $(this),
      data = $a.data('popup');
  createPopup(data);
  return false;
});
```

Note that jQuery attaches data to DOM node in ‘native’ presentation, without converting them to JSON first.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of ways. A simple way is to pass the variable as JSON.

```
var js = "afunction('" + JSON.stringify(results[i]) + "');return false;"
tableContent += "<td>" + '<a onclick="' + js + '">Open ID Contents</a>' + "</td>"
```